# Laravel building manual password reset

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a custom password reset in my project and I am not quite sure if [Laravel Crypt function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/encryption) is a good solution in this case. I did not use Hash:make function because it puts forward slash into the hashed token, so the route gets kinda messed up.

What I am doing right now is:

- user posts reset form with email
- I build a link, with Crypt::encrypt() and store the crypted token, email and created_at in the database password_resets
- Once link is clicked, I check for user email password_resets, compare token from database and url, try encrypting the token.

Example link:

> http://localhost:8000/auth/reset/password?token=eyJpdiI6IjN2RUdiVnlLNGcraFVPV2tzMGRwN2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiUWRyOFR5Y0x5SXRKVURTRFUySmZBZz09IiwibWFjIjoiYzlhOWM3ZDUyMjhmYjExY2I2ZGVlZGQ0OTNjY2ZkNTkwMzA0OTU0Mjk4M2JlODJhMmMxN2RlNTY4ZGM5NmFiNCJ9&email=example@example.com"

The token is pretty big with this function also I am not sure if I am doing all of this right.

Should I store the url token into the database or the token before hashing or encryption?

Comment: Passwords should never be encrypted but hashed! They are not supposed to be decrypted! Use bcrypt() or some other hashing functions.

Comment: @lewis4u I get that but I am not encrypting password I am encrypting some token in my case it is unix time. Anyway I am not sure if token in database and in url should be the same? Or token in database should be hashed and url one not? Or other way around?